# How to retrieve sharepoint 2013 list/document library in a .Net application that is hosted in local IIS?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

There are multiple solution do it, using rest api, csom, server side code by including Microsoft.sharepoint dll but all will work only, if the user is **authenticated** or **pass the network credentials** or User should be in the network/domain itself. 
Is it possible to retrieve values from different sharepoint onpermises site [without passing the credentials] and show it in a singe ASP.net web application [may be internet application] ?

Please suggest if any workaround is present ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible, You're requesting to break SharePoint security,

I would recommend to use impersonation and connect using a service account.

every single application or service that connects to SharePoint requires at least a service account.